# Using director.js, how do I define a default route for the site root which has no # hash in it?

Tags: javascript, routes, client-side, flatiron.js

I'm using [flatiron/director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) to do client-side routing.

I have routes like:

```
  var routes = {
    '': function() { loadLandingPage(); },
    '/author': function() { author(); }
  };
```

If I go to www.example.com#/author, it triggers the author function. If I go to www.example.com# or www.example.com#/ then my landing page is loaded.

However, I want to define a default route for the root of my site without the #. I want the landing page to load even when we land on www.example.com without the #.

I have looked through the documentation, but for the life of me can not figure it out. I thought that the [configuration: notfound](https://github.com/flatiron/director#configuration) method would do what I'm thinking, but it did nothing. I tried the following:

```
var router = Router(routes).configure({ notfound: loadGlobalPage});
```

and

```
var router = Router(routes).configure({ notfound: function () {loadGlobalPage();} });
```

and also after reading [this thread](https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron/issues/40), I tried:

```
router.notfound = function() {
    loadGlobalPage();
};
```

I also tried a hack unrelated to the router:

```
function determineIfLandingPage() {
    if (window.location.hash == "") {
        loadGlobalPage();
        window.location.href += "#"
    }
}
```

This works but it feels like a hack.

This must be a somewhat common use case--how do I get the desired functionality from my router?

Answer (score 3):

From the document: [redirect method](https://github.com/flatiron/director#initredirect) will solve this problem.

`route.init(['/'])` will redirect to the route `/` if `'/#/'` is not found in the URL.

Comment: Great answer. But you have a small typo :). Can you please edit it. It should be route.init(['/']). You are missing 't' in init.